# C: Loop only prints the last index

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

I am new to C, so excuse me for asking a seemingly easy question. but I have a loop which loops depending on the user, and inside the loops it asks for a name and an age, however when I go to print, it only prints the last entry and not all the entries I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size,age;
    char name [30];

    printf("How long to loop for: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter first name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);

        printf("Enter %s's age: ",name);
        scanf("%d",&age);

        printf("name: %s, age: %d\n", name,age);
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The title says, "Loop only prints last index," but as it stands, your programme can be on-line and doesn't require any extra memory. A print loop after the input loop would be less confusing.

Comment: When I run your code at [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/H19hbBwM_) it reads and prints each name and age after they're read in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your `name` and `age` variables will only hold the last input they received, thats why you're program only prints the last index. You need an array of `int` as well as an array of `char []` to "hold" each input they receive, otherwise those inputs get lost and you only get input for the last index.

your variables should be initialized like:

```
int size;
printf("Enter size: ");
scanf("%d", &size);

int age [size];
char name[size][30];
```

in order to get user input and print each entry you will need to access each index by looping through the array size.
to access each index:

```
age[i]
name[i]
```

Please Note: using `scanf` to get a string from user input is generally bad, as it can cause problems if you happen to use a space(such as inputting your full name for example) in your input, and it can cause a buffer overflow if your string is longer than the buffer. Instead you can use `fgets`, but for your question it isn't necessary, just something to considered in the future in case you want to have  spaces in your inputs.

Comment: The closing brace of the `for` loop is after the `printf` - So it prints all entries

Comment: `int age [size];` and `char name[size][30];` use `size` while it's still **not initialised!**

Comment: funny, I never showed you my implementation of it, did you assume I didn't initialize size already?

Comment: Well, that's your fault :)

Comment: I assumed `sized` was already initialized,and I just showed him how to make an array, I didn't want to give too much away

Comment: By showing only the variable declarations it's easy to assume that they should replace the ones of the OP, while in fact they should be placed after the call to `scanf()`

Comment: no , thats your fault for assuming I didn't initialize, If I showed the full code maybe you could've  assumed, but I added the three lines of code to explicitly show that `size` was initialized before `age[size]` and `name[size][30]`

Comment: Why does the values need to be stored in an array?

Comment: @EdHeal Because OP wanted to print all the data read with `scanf()`, albeit it wasn't much clear from the question

Comment: @JackLithammers `printf("name: %s, age: %d\n", name,age);` does that. Just after they are entered

Comment: @Neil - That is not clear in the question. It is an assumption that you are making

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I know, but I'm guessing that he wanted a separate loop to print them all after reading them

Comment: @JackLilhammers - I think the poster should be more clear on that point

Comment: @sjw037 If you'd have shown the full code I wouldn't have to assume. However, thank you for editing your answer

Comment: I read "entries" so I thought of arrays, either way, if OP wanted to access his inputs then he should make arrays, if he wanted to print the output AFTER his inputs  instead of in-between inputs then a separate loop or arrays are needed. But it seems he's accepted the answer and has moved on

Comment: This is a good, very simple answer. It should be noted that this only works reliably in `C99`; `C90` does not have VLAs and `C11` made them optional.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure that the first `scanf` actually reads a number.

You want the following to check

```
if (scanf(" %d", &size) != 1) { // Note space - Eats white space/new lines
   printf("Error - invalid size\nExiting\n");
   return -1;
}
```

2. Prevent buffer overruns

Use:

```
 scanf(" %29s", name); // See above
```

3. See point 1 for age

I think this will solve your problems

Comment: Yes , the first scanf reads a number correctly,. However my question was how to print ALL entries, but my code only prints the last entry.

Comment: My check checks if it has read correctly. You code prints all entries - as it prints them as it goes. The `printf` is in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if I am understanding you correctly, you are looping through the for loop size number of times and each time you are setting the contents of the variables age and name. It sounds like you are expecting each iteration through the loop to save your entered instance of age and name but this is not the case.

Since you only have one age and one name variable they are going to store whatever the most recently taken input was. So this means whatever was entered on the last loop is what was last written into the variables name and age.

If you then try to print the contents of those variables you are going to see whatever was most recently entered into those variables. you would need more than one name and more than one age variable to write into if you were trying to save multiple entries.

Okay so Anthony, maybe you need to try a little bit of review when it comes to allocating memory. So when we declare the variable
int age;
we are telling the compiler to allocate enough memory to store one single integer that we will call 'age' in our program. since we only asked for enough memory to store one integer, every time you scanf() into the age variable, the single integer is written into that space.

What you want is to store a new integer every time you do another run through your for loop. So, you could declare an array of integers as follows.

int age[20];

Now we have asked the compiler to allocate enough space to store 20 different integers. there will an integer in position age[0] and another integer in age[1] and another in age[2] so on. So now you could use a loop to index through your array and store each entered age from stdin into a different position in the array as follows

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    scanf("%i", &age[i]);
}
```

So this loop starts with i=0 and so enters the input from stdin to age[0], the next iteration through the loop has i=1 and so enters the stdin input to age[1] and so on.

Hopefully this clarifies things a bit more?

Comment: I need examples please, i am still new to C.

Answer (score 0):

A major fault is that your `printf`s will not be displayed as they are buffered.

You need a `fflush` after them

i.e.

```
printf("How long to loop for: ");
fflush(stdout);
```

And

```
printf("Enter first name: ");
fflush(stdout);
```

etc...